# How to not have inspections and language injections in diff? Makes identical code look different

Tags: intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting, phpstorm

I'm using several of JetBrains' products, like IntelliJ IDEA, PyCharm and PhpStorm. One issue I'm having is that when viewing a diff codelines will look different even though they are identical.

[image: diff1]
([full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpNOX.png))

The lines are identical, but the rendering of them are different. That's pretty annoying, as it's hard to spot where there are actual differences.
This example can be mostly solved by turning off inspections, but that turns them off for the whole project, and I will need to constantly enable and disable it.

[image: diff2]
([full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IHjH.png))

In this example, there's also no differences. And there are no highlighting from inspections. But still the code is rendered differently. The comment reminded my that this is because of language injections. Turning them off makes stuff look right, but I want them when I work.

How can I make my diff become more readable and the differences easier to spot without all the clutter and without disabling everything?

Comment: *"But still the code is rendered differently."* That's clearly a **Language Injection** (SQL and HTML accordingly). Disable them completely in `Settings | Language Injections` of desired. *"without all these false positives?"* False Positives? ... Mmm Ok. But usability issue in general -- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-16394

Comment: @LazyOne I don't want them gone, only not shown this way in the diff. By *false positives* I mean stuff that's highlighted that's not changes. Updated my Q.

Comment: *"How can I make my diff become more readable and the differences easier to spot without all the clutter and without disabling everything?"* -- you cannot, unfortunately (at very least I do not know how). I gave you the ticket already -- comment there and maybe dev will pay attention to this and it will make its way into PhpStorm v7 (or at very least IDEA v13, which then may appear later in v7.x)

Comment: Forgot to add: even if it may not be 100% correct ticket (as it talks about markers on sidebar rather than editor area itself) .. it will not hurt commenting there. At very least devs should either point you to more appropriate ticket (which I'm not aware of) .. or should ask you (or do it themselves) to create ticket for this specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been possible for a while now to change this just for a diff-view. For instance when committing, one can press the cog and change `Highlighting Level`.